# Monogo DB Update Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Tags: mongodb, express

So I am using my Express server to try update an array on my MongoDB.

My data looks like this:

```
  {
            "ID": "1",
            "Name": "John",
            "Image URL": "https://www.bnl.gov/today/body_pics/2017/06/stephanhruszkewycz-hr.jpg",
            "Email": "",
            "userSkillIds": ["1","2"]
        },
        {
            "ID": "2",
            "Name": "Sarah",
            "Image URL": "https://www.venmond.com/demo/vendroid/img/avatar/big.jpg",
            "Email": "",
            "userSkillIds": ["3"]
        },
```

I am trying to insert just a single String number in to the userSkillIds array using this code

```
router.put('/task/:id',function(req,res,next) {
    var obj = req.body; 
    let skillId = obj.skillId; 
    if(obj == null || obj == {} ) {
        res.status(400);
        res.json({
            "error": "Bad Data"
        });
    }else {
        db.tasks.update(
            { _id: mongojs.ObjectID(req.params.id)},
            { $push: { userSkillIds: { 1: skillId } } }
         )
         res.json();
    }
});
```

However I continuously get the error Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

May be your syntax is incorrect, use push operator as follows

db.tasks.update( { _id: 1 }, { $push: { userSkillIds: 89 } } )